# Create a Table from a Data frame with some conditions

Tags: r

From the following data frame, I am trying to output two tables, one for `PASS` and another one for `FAIL`. The condition is that the output for each table should contain only the `ID` and the `Score`. Can anyone help me with this? I am still starting to know the full capabilities of the table function. If anyone could suggest other alternatives I would greatly appreciate it as long as the conditions for the output is met.

```
> df <- data.frame(
          ID <-  as.factor(c(20260, 11893, 54216, 11716, 53368, 46196, 40007, 20970, 11802, 46166, 23615, 11865, 16138, 64789, 43211, 66539));
          Score <- c(9,7,6,2,10,7,8,10,6,7,7,9,9,9,10,8)
          Remark<- as.factor(c("PASS","PASS","FAIL","FAIL","PASS","PASS","PASS","PASS","FAIL","PASS","PASS","PASS","PASS","PASS","PASS","PASS"))
)
> df
      ID Score Remark
1  20260     9   PASS
2  11893     7   PASS
3  54216     6   FAIL
4  11716     2   FAIL
5  53368    10   PASS
6  46196     7   PASS
7  40007     8   PASS
8  20970    10   PASS
9  11802     6   FAIL
10 46166     7   PASS
11 23615     7   PASS
12 11865     9   PASS
13 16138     9   PASS
14 64789     9   PASS
15 43211    10   PASS
16 66539     8   PASS
```

Comment: Not sure if you need the `table` function. I think the [`subset`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/subset.html) function is what you're looking for.

Comment: @bouncyball, yes, it would be very easy if it were the case. However, as part of testing our skills in data manipulation, we are asked to output such conditions.

Comment: @venrey `table` is not meant for what you are describing. I would recommend asking your instructor for clarification. Besides, there is not a `table` class (that I know of) in `R`. I believe `table` outputs a `matrix`.

Comment: @Clarinetist we've asked him already and he just smiled back to us. So somehow he's kind of expert with this things for years now and he never gives something that is not possible.

Comment: Is it possible the instructor means `data.table` and not `table`?

Comment: @bouncyball, RIGHT! I never thought of that. I think it's really possible. GREAT!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID =  as.factor(c(20260, 11893, 54216, 11716, 53368, 46196, 40007, 20970, 11802, 46166, 23615, 11865, 16138, 64789, 43211, 66539)),
  Score = c(9,7,6,2,10,7,8,10,6,7,7,9,9,9,10,8),
  Remark = as.factor(c("PASS","PASS","FAIL","FAIL","PASS","PASS","PASS","PASS","FAIL","PASS","PASS","PASS","PASS","PASS","PASS","PASS"))
)

df[df$Remark == "PASS", 1:2]

      ID Score
1  20260     9
2  11893     7
5  53368    10
6  46196     7
7  40007     8
8  20970    10
10 46166     7
11 23615     7
12 11865     9
13 16138     9
14 64789     9
15 43211    10
16 66539     8
```

Comment: Yes, it would look something like that but it should be a table, not a data frame. If we are to check the class of your answer, the result is `"data.frame"`.

Comment: @venrey, you can coerce objects using `as.*` methods. Like `as.matrix(x)`.